# How to clear ProcessInstanceNode records?

Tags: approval-process, data-storage, storage-limit, processinstancenode

I was checking my org's data usage and I found that Process Instance Node consumes most of the space in my org(38%). 
Is there any way if we can delete process instance node records without disturbing the org's data?

If there is any way to delete this data, will it effect the target object records?

Example : Suppose if I have a approval process on account object and I want to clear Process Instance Node records, Will there be any  effect on existing approved records after deleting process instance node records ?

Any kind of help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> ProcessInstanceNode
>
> Represents a step in an instance of an approval process. Compare to ProcessNode, which describes the step in a process definition. Use this object to retrieve approval history.

If you delete the entries then history records of approval process will be lost. It's up to your strategy for deletion or archival of records.

Process Data Model

[image: Process Data Model]

Comment: if I delete the entries then history records will be deleted. So my existing approved target object records won't be effected right ?

Comment: And is processInstanceNode is read only objcet? Which is the better way to delete those records ?

Comment: I tried deleteing the records via workbench. It is giving me this error "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY : Insufficient Access Rights On Object Id"

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria quite late to this, but were you able to delete these records?